# Response.Redirect se ejecuta como un ciclo dentro de un metodo en asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hola comunidad tengo un problema con el re direccionamiento de formularios en asp.net c# al cargar por primera vez la pagina ya que este se sigue ejecutando como si fuera un ciclo espero me puedan ayudar porque la verdad no entiendo este comportamiento de antemano gracias.

Aquí coloco mi código. es mi método de cargar menú según el usuario

```
 private void Cargar_Menu()
    {
        DataRow row;
        DataTable user_datos = new DataTable();            
        string nombre_usuario = usuario.Name;            
        Menu = t.Mostrar_Menu(nombre_usuario);
        _menuPadre = Menu.Tables[1];
        if (_menuPadre.Rows.Count == 0)
        {
            Response.Redirect("direccion web", true); //Aqui todo lo hace correcto

        } 
        else
        {                
            row = _menuPadre.Rows[0];
            rptMenu.DataSource = t.Mostrar_MenuSubmenu(nombre_usuario);
            rptMenu.DataBind();
            user_datos = Menu.Tables[0];
            row = user_datos.Rows[0];
            lblNombre_Usuario.Text = row[1].ToString();
            Response.Redirect("~/default.aspx"); // Al llegar a este punto se va al método IsPosback y posteriormente vuelve a entrar al método y se sigue ejecutando impidiendo poder visualizar la pagina
        }
```

Aquí es donde lo mando a llamar.

```
  if (!IsPostBack)
        {               

            this.Cargar_Menu();

        }
```

Comment: El `IsPostBack` a que paguina le pertenece a `default.aspx` si es asi, entonce elimina el redirect que tiene en el `else` de esta forma se sigue el flujo normal.

Comment: Hola @OrlandoDeLaRosa el IsPostBack pertenece a mi pagina maestra.

Comment: Pasate por este [enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18148763), revisa si te funciona saber si el request ya viene de la pagina default.aspx y si es asi no haces el redireccionamiento que tienes en el else.

Comment: tbn puede probar la sobrecarga de [`Redirect`](https://support.microsoft.com/es-pa/help/307903/how-to-use-response-redirect-in-asp-net-with-visual-c-net) o utilizar [`Server.Transfer`](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/3d39b4/difference-between-response-redirect-and-server-transfer/)

Comment: Hola @Orlando he probado con el codigo de arriba que me enviaste en el enlace y me funciona gracias por tu ayuda.